# Loading screen is not working properly

Tags: iphone, uiview

In my app I am showing loading screen when request is sent to server and when response is received I am removing that loading screen.

To display loading screen I used `UIView` and reduce its **alpha** to **0.5** so that it shows the background view.

**My problem is** user is able to click button displayed on background view when loading screen is still visible.

**What I want is:** User should not be able to click anywhere on the screen when loading screen is visible. Even though I made `userInteractionEnabled` **false** for `UIView` but still user is able to click on button, why?

If any one knows where I am doing wrong and how I can achieve this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try SVProgressHUD? And userInteractionEnabled should be NO for the view that is below the loading screen, i.e the view that contains the button.

Comment: No, I have not tried SVProgressHUD it is already implemented this way and I want to show loading screen even if some internal processing is going on.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your view hierarchy. because normally if you set userinteractionenabled:no on the view, buttons which are subviews of the view shouldn't be clickable. perhaps check again how you set your uibutton on to the background view

Comment: I have added button on main view ie [self.view addSubView:myButton] and even loading view on main view as  [self.view addSubView:myLoadingView];

Comment: Yes I got it I did userInteractionEnabled false for UIView so the click event was sent to the button which was on main view.I removed userInteractionEnabled false and it is working fine.Thanx everyone.

Comment: Great that you found it. Dont forget to accept the answer of Elmo - he explained the same thing I commented here.

Comment: I am greatly thankful for your answers, but I think answer to my question is not what is suggested by Elmo.I had altogether different problem, it was not because of view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The UIView may have interaction disabled but if the button is higher on the view hierarchy then its on TOP of the view so it's still accessible.

If this is a view made in the nib then make sure its at the top of the view stack

Or if its programmatically then add it as a subview at the end of the function or add it mainWindow (be VERY careful adding things to main Window, this is the top of the hierarchy)

Comment: I have added button on main view ie [self.view addSubView:myButton] and then when user clicks on button I am adding loading view on main view as [self.view addSubView:myLoadingView];

Answer (score 0):

Like wise the utility open source library  available.

iOS open source project is MBProgressHUD,

it refers to Heads Up Display, a view that is overlayed on another view, typically to show an activity indicator and/or offer a means to interact with the UI. A good example of an HUD is when playing a movie with the built in movie player. When you tap the screen, the movie player will show a series of controls on the display. Another common example, and one that is pertinent to MBProgressHUD, is showing progress indicators on top of an existing view. For example, when accessing a remote service, to provide feedback to the user you may opt to display a “Please Wait” message

you can download the [source code from here](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got it, I did userInteractionEnabled false for UIView so the click event was sent to the button which was on main view.I removed userInteractionEnabled false and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents] when you are sending request to server & shows loading view.When you receives the response call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents] & remove the loading view.